# Unable to access field members of struct in another .c file

Tags: c, pointers, struct, forward-declaration

I've created a complex number struct and wrote functions to create it like this: In Complex.c:

```
typedef struct Complex
{
    double m_re;
    double m_im;
}Complex;

ComplexP fromCharFunc(char *s)
{

    double *values = extractValuesFromString(s);

    if(values == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    double re = values[0], im = values[1];
    free(values);

    return createComplexNumber(re, im);
}


static ComplexP createComplexNumber(double re, double im)
{
     ComplexP complexNumber = (ComplexP)malloc(sizeof(Complex));

     complexNumber->m_re = re;
     complexNumber->m_im = im;

     return complexNumber;
}
```

and this in Complex.h:

```
typedef struct Complex* ComplexP;
```

So to check if what I Done is ok I created a main function in the Complex.c file and called

```
ComplexP a = fromCharFunc("0,1i");
a->m_im = 3;
```

And everything worked just fine.

But when I did it in another .c file with this in top:

```
#include "Complex.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

and with the same main function, it gave me this error on the second line in the main function: "dereferencing pointer to incomplete type". I read about it in another post and the people there said there was no memory allocated... but I did allocate memory and it did not happen in Complex.c file.

Please help. Thanks

EDIT: I'm not allowed to change the header file. School Homework

Comment: Since the header file is fixed, post it.  Certain something _else_ in there is useful.

Comment: There is nothing else of relevance there. Just some methods I didn't yet had  the chance to call in my new .c file. Nothing of importance to allocating memory and creating variables of this struct.

Comment: If you can't change the header, you'll have to create access functions to get at the members.  You can't access the members unless you can see the structure definition — and the opaque type in the header doesn't allow that.  Some of those unimplemented functions in the header probably provide the access you need.

Comment: It is those "methods I didn't yet had the chance to call" that is the solution to the problem.

Comment: I understood the problem with @JonathanLeffler answer. Thank you all!

Answer (score 2):

You should move

```
typedef struct Complex
{
    double m_re;
    double m_im;
}Complex;
```

in `Complex.h`.

That's because the newly created type `ComplexP` is referring to `Complex`.

*Update for the change in the question*: If the header file `Complex.h` must not be changed, you either have to copy the definition of the `Complex` type in the other `.c` files,  or create another header file containing the type definition, and to include it in the `.c` files. But that's clearly not how it is intended to be used.

Answer (score 1):

"dereferencing pointer to incomplete type" is good.  It shows that `main.c` code is attempting to access the details of a structure it does not know about - or should know.

```
a->m_im = 3;
```

This is called information hiding.  The `complex.h` has the following opaque pointer.

```
typedef struct Complex* ComplexP;
```

Certainly there are other methods (function prototypes) that allow access to the `ComplexP` inside  `complex.h` and *that* is what `main()` should use rather than `a->m_im = 3;`

Answer (score 1):

You need to practice good encapsulation.  Your header file does this by hiding the type of `Complex` by just forward declaring the type.

There must be some other methods in the header file which can help you here.  you can either compare two complex numbers to see if they are the same, e.g.

```
ComplexP a = fromCharFunc("0,1i");
ComplexP b = createCompleNumber(0,1);
if (compareComplex(a, b)) {
    printf("Success\n");
} else {
    printf("Try again\n");
}
```

Or there are printing functions, e.g.

```
ComplexP a = fromCharFunc("0,1i");
printComplexNumber(a);
```

Or perhaps there are functions to return the real and imaginary parts:

```
  ComplexP a = fromCharFunc("0,1i");
  printf("Real: %f, Imaginary: %f\n", complexRealComponent(a), complexImaginaryComponent(a));
```

Since I can't see the rest of the header and you refuse to post it I had to guess at what the functions are called.  I am guessing at least one of these exist.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the struct `Complex` in `Complex.h` (or somewhere that is visible from the main function). Otherwise, the compiler won't know what members `Complex` has and won't be able to access them.